# Добавление скролла div блоку с другими блоками внутри

Tags: javascript, html

Есть окно чата с сообщениями (обычный div со свойством max-height: 100vh), каждое сообщение в отдельном div блоке. Как добавить для этого окна внутренний скролл?

Comment: _"Есть окно чата..."_ Где оно есть? Покажите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужному div блоку задайте css свойство overflow-y:

```
div.your-css-class {
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll; /*по вертикали*/
}
```

Или

```
div.your-css-class {
  height: 100px;
  overflow-x: scroll; /*по горизонтали*/
}
```

При значении **scroll** прокрутка будет отображаться всегда, а при значении **auto** - когда блок превысит заданную высоту.

Comment: overflow-y: scroll работает только для текста. С div блоками внутри не работает

Comment: @LYAGUSHKA вот, посмотри (https://jsfiddle.net/k4t5jbdn/)

Comment: да, все работает. Просто свойство justify-content: flex-end почему-то не давало скроллить